# Find next empty cell for the end cell of a range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I want to select a range from A2 to the next blank cell in column F to copy. I am using this to paste the values to the cell instead of the formula in column A and B. The select I am using now is:

```
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going up from the bottom (which selects ALL rows with data), for the first blank we come from the top down:

```
Range("A2:F" & range("F2").End(xlDown).Row).select
```

Doing it Andy G's way:

```
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 6).End(xlDown)).Select
```

They are exactly the same number of chars, My way is easier to read, Andy's is easier (MUCH easier) to incorporate into looping, your choice.

Answer (score 0):

`.Row` returns a number, you need a range-reference. Remove `.Row`:

```
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp)).Select
```

but this selects the last non-empty cell, use xlDown to find the first empty cell. Use `Offset(1, 0)` if you want to extend the range to include the empty cell.